# How to properly include external css and js files in index.html served with express/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to wrap my html in a nodejs express app (latest version of express). I try using res.sendFile to send my "index.html" file. I am running into an issue where there are a lot of 404s when loading the page in a browser because it can't find any of my js or css files. My js files are in the bower_components directory, some are in "js" directory. My css files are in a "css" directory.

Path for one is:

```
/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

What is the best way to update in my server.js file and my index.html file so that it can find all the "css" and "js" files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the directive [express.static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html)

```
var server = express();
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

It will look for a static folder to serve your static files. Just put your css and js files in this folder and reference them in the `<head>` part of your templates (index.html in your case)

Answer (score 2):

If you have this two line of code in your app.js file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Then you need to put your HTML files in view folder.
I myself use `ejs` (templator) for render HTML files and more ,by adding this line of code to my app.js :

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then by changing your extention of HTML fils to .ejs you can render them with this code :

```
res.render('file_name');
```

**More info**

For example if you have a css file in `/public/css/style.css` you have to link to it in your html with this address : `./css/style.css` or something like this.