# AMP: External amp css using {%...%}

Tags: css, amp-html

I keep seeing people say AMP pages must have the css code all inline in the custom tag, but on the website it seems to say you can reference it from an external file for when its from a preprocessor: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages#using-css-preprocessors

Can someone tell me if I'm interpreting this wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You can use as many external files as you want *provided* their content is included in a single amp-html output stream.

Answer (score 1):

**{% include "/assets/css/main.min.css" %}** is Twig Tag (The flexible, fast, and secure template engine for PHP). For more details [**Click Here**](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/index.html)

You can use like this if using PHP language

```
<style amp-custom>
    <?php include("styles.css"); ?>
</style>
```

**include : The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.**

> Note : styles.css is external css

Comment: So then you can actually use external style sheets with amp? Any way to do it if you're not using php? (I use node.js)

Comment: Please refer to this Question may this will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128716/2777138